# how can i compare within a group in python without using "import" or pandas?

Tags: python

so I currently have a data in csv file that looks like this:

```
class   name.  grade 

grade 5 john.   4
grade 5 elias   5
grade 6 john     6
grade 6 elias    4
```

and I need to compare the grades of john and elias for each grade
and print like this:

```
class      winner 
grade 5    elias 
grade 6    john
```

I am not allowed to use any import or pandas

this is what I have so far:

```
data = dict()
with open("summary.csv", "r", encoding="cp949") as f:
    heads = f.readline().split("\t")
    for line in f:
        class,name,grade = line.split(',')
        data[class] = data.setdefault(state, dict())
```

I am not sure how to proceed afterward.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @JaredSmith OP said no import

Comment: What is `state` in the last line ?

Comment: @Frodon I know, but unlike pandas csv is in the standard library, you don't have to mess with installing dependencies.

Comment: one immediately evident problem is you're using the reserved word 'class' as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly split the data, I suppose that they are comma-separated in the CSV file:

```
class   name.  grade 

grade 5,john.,4
grade 5,elias,5
grade 6,john,6
grade 6,elias,4
```

Then here is a solution to retrieve the best students for each class. It uses 2 dictionaries: one for the link classname/student name, the other for the link class name/best grade.

```py
data = dict()
grades = dict()
with open("summary.csv", "r", encoding="cp949") as f:
    heads = f.readline().split("\t")
    for line in f:
        # Ignore empty lines
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        # The split can be encased in a try/except block
        # to deal with lines without 2 commas
        classname, name, grade = line.split(',')
        # Ignore line where last element is not a integer
        if not grade.strip().isdigit():
            continue
        # Convert string to integer
        grade = int(grade.strip())
        # Update best name if the current grade is higher
        # than the stored one in grades
        if grade > grades.get(classname.strip(), -1):
            data[classname.strip()] = name.strip()
            grades[classname.strip()] = grade

print("class\twinner")
for classname, best in data.items():
    print("{}\t{}".format(classname, best))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that follows from your code and uses a dictionary of lists to store the winners. First loop reads the file and stores as a list. Second loop iterates through the list to pick winners.

```
data = dict()
l = []
with open("yas.csv", "r", encoding="cp949") as f:
    heads = f.readline().split("\t")
    for line in f:
        cl,name,grade = line.split(',')
        # append to a list
        l.append([cl, name, grade])

for x in l:
    # get rid of line break if necessary
    x = [sub.replace('\n', '') for sub in x]
    gradekey = x[0]
    name = x[1]
    score = int(x[2])
    
    # data is dictionary of lists, containing winners only
    if gradekey in data.keys():
        # if we have a new winner, put it in the dictionary
        data[gradekey] = [name, max(data[gradekey][1], score)]
        
    else:
        # this is the first one for this grade, enter it as the current winner
        data[gradekey] = [name, score]
        
print('Winners are', data)
```

Output is:

```
Winners are {'grade 5': ['elias', 5], 'grade 6': ['elias', 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

let us first specifiy `yas.csv` file to be:

```
class,name,grade
grade 5,john.,4
grade 5,elias,5
grade 6,john,6
grade 6,elias,4
```

Then the could would be

```
data = dict()
with open("yas.csv", "r", encoding="cp949") as f:
    heads = f.readline()  
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(',')
        if a[0] in data.keys():
            if data[a[0]][1] < a[2]:
                data[a[0]] = (a[1], a[2])
        else:
            data[a[0]] = (a[1], a[2])
```

```
# output
print('class', 'winner')
for k, v in data.items():
    print(k, v[0])
```

The output is

```
class    winner
grade 5    elias
grade 6    john
```